# Does CloudFlare protect the underlying OS and web server from vulnerabilities?

Tags: cloudflare

I understand that CloudFlare protects your application against attacks like SQL and XSS injections. But what about the operating system and web server?

For example, if my website is hosted on IIS/Windows, will CloudFlare also protect against operating system vulnerabilities and/or IIS vulnerabilities on my server?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare protection come in the form of a [Web Application Firewall](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall) (WAF). This is available (currently) to all paid plan users. The WAF scans all web requests according to certain rules defined by CloudFlare, and the website owner. These rules are in place to protect against certain coding and application vulnerabilities in the event they are not protected against in the website's code or software.

While CloudFlare has blocked certain vulnerabilities like [CVE-2015-1635](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-is-protected-against-cve-2015-1635/) and [Shellshock](https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/). These all were vulnerabilities that could be exploited through a HTTP request.

If your server or operating system or software has a vulnerability that does not correspond directly with web requests, then CloudFlare is not likely to be interested in blocking it.

It should also be noted that CloudFlare does not *actually* fix the vulnerability on your server, rather blocks any requests that come through CloudFlare that clearly are attempting to exploit a vulnerability. You should always still attempt to patch the vulnerability as soon as possible.

**In Short:**
If a vulnerability can be exploited through a common HTTP request, CloudFlare is likely to block it. All other vulnerabilities are likely to be ignored by CloudFlare, as they have no way to block them in the first place.